How to dynamically apply a class to a child component?
I have a child component within a parent component. Whenever the child component is clicked, I need to apply a class called .selected to it.
Parent.vue
<template>
   <ol>
    <li v-for="(Contact, index) in Contacts">
      <Component-Contact :ref="(el) => { RefContacts[index] = el}" @click="onClick(RefContacts[index])" :Contact="Contact" @Selected="(Data) => onSelected(Data)"/>
     </li>
   </ol>

</template>
<script>
import ComponentContact from '../components/Contact.vue'
....
setup() {
const RefContacts = ref([]);

function onSelected(Contact){
  //Adds data received from child component to an array
}

onClick(el) {
 el.toggleClass('selected') // Returns error saying toggleClass is not a function!!
}

 const Contacts = ref();
 onMounted(() => {
    const Result = await axios.get(`/api/contacts`);
    Contacts.value = Result.data
}
 )

return {
  Contacts, // An array of contacts from the DB
  onSelected
}
}
</script>

Child component Contact.vue
<template>
 <div style="cursor: pointer" @click="onClick($el, Contact)">
  <p>{{Contact.Forename}}</p>
  <p>{{Contact.Surname}}</p>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
...
props: {
  Contact: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
   },
emits: 'Selected',
setup() {

  function onClick(el, Contact) {
   el.toggleClass('selected') // This works but I don't want to set it here in the child
   return context.emit('Selected', {
   FullName: Contact.forename + ' ' + Contact.surname
   }
 }

}
</script>

How can I get Vue to apply the class of .selected to the <Child-Component /> within the Parent.vue view? I want to set it in the Parent (or wherever else its being used) and then remove the class when the user finished doing what hes doing .I feel this is more flexible than setting it within the child component.

Where is Contacts defined? There's a need for "selected" state, could  be a part of Contacts if it's convenient

@EstusFlask I updated the question to show where it is defined. It is in Parent component and comes from a backend API using axios. It is an Array of Objects (each Object has details of the Contact e.g. forename, surname, username...

I see. Can you explain how is this supposed to work? What's the difference between "Selected" and "click" in a parent, is there a need to emit "FullName"? Is "select" needs to be toggled multiple times?

@EstusFlask Selected is data about the contact that is emitted from the child. It will always emit data about the contact. It is the parent that deals with the toggle. Really theres no difference between Selected and @click.

@EstusFlask After thinking about your question, I have moved the data emitted from the child into the Parent itself. So instead of emitting "FullName" I can get that from Contacts.value[index].forename+'  '+Contacts.value[index].forename within the Parent

Refrain from DOM manipulation as much as possible.
Instead of applying the class yourself, let Vue do it:
<my-component :class="{ selected: /* condition here */ }" />

See Class and Style Bindings.

Basic example, where only one item can be selected (selecting another unselects the previous one):


const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const selected = ref(null)
    return {
      selected,
      select: (index) =>
        (selected.value = selected.value === index ? null : index)
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.5.4/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(_, index) in 6"
      @click="() => select(index)"
      :class="{ selected: index === selected }"
      v-text="'item'"
    />
  </ul>
  <pre v-text="JSON.stringify({ selected }, null, 2)" />
</div>




And here's one where you can select items individually:


const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = ref(
      Array.from({ length: 7 }).map(() => ({ selected: false }))
    )
    return {
      items,
      toggle: (index) =>
        items.value.splice(index, 1, { selected: !items.value[index].selected })
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
}
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.5.4/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="({ selected }, index) in items"
      @click="() => toggle(index)"
      :class="{ selected }"
      v-text="'item'"
    />
  </ul>
  <pre v-text="JSON.stringify( { items }, null, 2)" />
</div>




In each case, I'm keeping a minimal local state (in parent). When the state is modified, Vue updates the template.

Wow that was a lot of hoops to jump through for a toggle but it works. Thank you tao - if everything has to be data driven then simple DOM manipulation is going to take a long time.

You're not supposed to do DOM manipulation in Vue, because it's lost when Vue updates. Modify the data and the template updates.

You're right. I'm just saying using toggleClass() is a lot quicker/easier than it being done through data.

@volumeone depends if you need to update the state in 10 different places or not. Vue can be very powerful but you indeed need a minimal amount of complexity to see the benefits. Feel free to also give a try to script setup for an even shorter and simpler approach.

@kissu i tried script setup and didn't get on with it. found it confusing.

@volumeone as a whole, VueJS is quite different from regular vanilla JS DOM manipulation approach, requires some time to get used to the framework, take it easy and you'll see why it's nice at some point and if it suits your use-case.

@kissu thanks. I have just switched to <script setup> like you suggested. i didnt realise they introduced defineOptions which makes all the difference.

@volumeone script setup improves quite a lot of things + things move quite fast in the right direction too in terms of DX yes!
